# Is there any way to pass external file path in user.properties

Tags: jmeter

When ever external files  required need be add or update in multiple machines in bin/ext instead of going to each and every machine keep all the jars at one place or folder updating that folder automatically updates in all machines.

So there any way  and possible to pass jars path in user.properties file? For example: jdbc jars

Answer (score 0):

See [manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you can add to user.classpath:

> If you don't want to put such jars in the lib directory, then define the property user.classpath or plugin_dependency_paths in jmeter.properties ...
>
> jars (such as JDBC, JMS implementations and any other support libraries needed by the JMeter code) should be placed in the lib directory - not the lib/ext directory, or added to user.classpath.

Also in Test Plan you can add jar manually with path of the jars by click Browse and add specific jars.

Answer (score 0):

You can either amend/override an existing property or add a new property, they will be picked up on JMeter startup and will be accessible via [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) functions.

In order to add a .jar to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you will need to define  `user.classpath` property and specify the .jar path in it.

Also be aware that you can pass individual properties or property files to JMeter slave engines via [-G command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)